# Different art types

Tags: word-choice, terminology

*Performing arts* are forms of art that consist mainly of actions, such as choreographed movements, vocal expressions etc. So, basically, dancing, singing and theater.

There are other types of art — sculpting, painting, filming etc. I'd like to know what they're formally called.

Comment: You should write "art forms", not "arts' forms". Here "art" is just modifying "forms". There is no possession.

Comment: @user3169 I see your point. I intended it to be *the types that are belonging/related to art forms of different kinds* but perhaps the way I put it, there's a suspicion of confused misusage of apostrophe?

Comment: @KonradViltersten There are two reasons why "art forms" is better than "arts' forms": as "seen" in English, these forms don't belong to the specific performing arts, they _are_ specific performing arts; and "art form" is itself a fixed phrase. This would make a good new question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arts are usually broken down into two main categories:

> **Performing Arts** - singing, dancing, drama, music
>
> **Visual Arts** - painting, photography, graphics, calligraphy

there is also

> **Culinary Arts**

but that is usually under Hospitality Management in college courses.

Comment: There is also the term **plastic arts** which is a subset of visual arts that includes sculpture and other 3D art, and **literary arts** for poetry, novels, etc.

Comment: @Era In another language I've heard the term (loosely translated) "*beautiful arts*". Is that something that's additional to what's listed above or rather a subset to it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten "beautiful arts" isn't a common phrase in English. The closest equivalent I can think of would be [**fine arts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_art), which can encompass any type of art.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Perhaps you are thinking of *fine arts*, art which is created for the sole purpose of beauty (e.g. a painting or sculpture), in contrast to *decorative arts*, which are about beautifying everyday artifacts of living (e.g. pottery or smithery). *Beautiful arts* isn't a standard subdivision of art (especially as beauty is required to be art, by some definitions of art), but *[Beaux-Arts](http://architecturestyles.org/beaux-arts/)* is a style that was popular in the U.S. in the late 19th and early 20th centuries.

Comment: "Is that a pile of poop?", he asked. "No, it's Post Contemporary Deconstructed Modern Art", she said.